# JPA 2.1 : EclipseLink : Not all entities gets created

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am using JPA 2.1. Eclipse link as JPA implementation.

```
    The Persistence XML as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="DSProductCatalogPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/SampleDS</jta-data-source>
```

The following are having @Entity annotations in POJO classes

```
    <class>org.tmf.dsmapi.catalog.entity.catalog.CatalogEntity</class>
    <class>org.tmf.dsmapi.catalog.entity.category.CategoryEntity</class>
    <class>org.tmf.dsmapi.catalog.entity.product.ProductSpecificationEntity</class>
    <class>org.tmf.dsmapi.catalog.resource.product.ProductSpecification</class>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>

      <property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="true" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>

    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Some of the entities are getting created. Some not getting created.

Example: The following entities got  created CatalogEntity and CategoryEntity

Example: These following entities are not get created: ProductSpecificationEntity and ProductSpecification

Ideally these four tables should have created during server start up. But it is not. I am using wild fly 10.0 as a application server.

Any reason for this?

Comment: try changing `<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>` to `<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>`

Comment: Set logging to ALL and check the logs during deployment to find out why the 2 tables might not have been successfully created.